# How can I get my primary display to function while my secondary is plugged in at boot?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics

If I boot my Acer Aspire v5 laptop with my secondary display plugged in (hdmi) I see the POST screen on both primary and secondary display. Prior to arriving at the login screen my primary (laptop) display goes black and remains black even after logging in though secondary works fine.

I must unplug my hdmi prior to powering on my machine, boot, login, then plug it back in again in order to use my dual screen setup. Ideally I'd like to not have to unplug it at all.

It's a new installation, ubuntu 16.04 64bit, completely default setup.

monitors.xml appeared to have duplicate entries, I removed the file, configured my display layout and applied it;

```
<monitors version="1">
<configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="eDP1">
          <vendor>AUO</vendor>
          <product>0x31ec</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
          <width>1366</width>
          <height>768</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="DP1">
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI1">
          <vendor>ACR</vendor>
          <product>0x02e9</product>
          <serial>0x30800bc8</serial>
          <width>1600</width>
          <height>900</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>1366</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>no</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="VGA1">
      </output>
      <output name="VIRTUAL1">
      </output>
</configuration>
</monitors>
```

Other related information;

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2966 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      60.10*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1600x900+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 442mm x 249mm
   1600x900      60.00*+
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

more info;

```
# lspci  -v -s  $(lspci | grep VGA | cut -d" " -f 1)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Any insight would be appreciated, I have very limited experience with a full desktop, mostly used remote shells over the years, thank you. ^_^